# Python NetworkX adding list of edges with dict

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I want to add a list of tuples of edges to my GRaph, and some of the attributes are dictionary. The documentation seem to be able to accept dictionary but i am getting an error:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

edges = [(34, 1, {'id': '123a'}, {'date': '2017-11-27'}),
 (1, 27, {'id': '123a'}, {'date': '2017-11-27'})]

G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

**My error:**

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the edge attributes in a single dictionary:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

edges = [(34, 1, {'id': '123a', 'date': '2017-11-27'}),
 (1, 27, {'id': '123a', 'date': '2017-11-27'})]

G.add_edges_from(edges)
print(G[34][1][0]['id'])
```

ouput:

```
'123a'
```